# Query Active Directory by invoking powershell cmdlets from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to learn how to call PowerShell cmdlets from C# to get the contents of an Active Directory OU. I am using the PowerShell class to do this. I can get it to work for basic use, however now I wanted to execute this PS command:

```
 Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU="Unfiled Computers",OU="Admnet Computers",dc=domain,dc=controller,dc=edu' -Filter '*'
```

When I tried to build this using the PowerShell class in C#, I always get the exception
`A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'OU=Unfiled Computers'.`

Here is the code I use in C#

```
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddCommand("Get-ADComputer");
ps.AddParameter("-SearchBase");
ps.AddArgument("OU=Unfiled Computers");
ps.AddArgument("OU=Admnet Computers");
ps.AddArgument("dc=domain");
ps.AddArgument("dc=controller");
ps.AddArgument("dc=edu");
ps.AddParameter("-Filter");
ps.AddArgument("'*'");

foreach(PSObject result in ps.Invoke())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
```

Is it possible to execute this command in C# like this?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with escaping. Somehow, the command string as parsed after being sent from your program lacks the ':s. Could you post the code you use to pass the command?

Comment: I don't know anything about C#, but why are you adding the components of the DN as separate arguments? The **-SearchBase** parameter takes the DN as a single string argument, not an array of the components. I think the fourth through eighth lines should be replaced by the single line `ps.AddArgument("OU=Unfiled Computers,OU=Admnet Computers,DC=domain,DC=controller,DC=edu");`.

Comment: I tried using the single line approach you suggested, however I received the same exception as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the extraneous quotes.  That command query should look like this:

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 'OU=Unfiled Computers,OU=Admnet Computers,dc=domain,dc=controller,dc=edu' -Filter *
```

Comment: Thanks, that is definitely a cleaner way to write it, however the powershell command works fine, it's the C# code that is the problem.